# VMware player: make command gives warning clock skewed

Tags: make, vmware-player

I am a beginner at ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu on VMware player on windows. When i try to compile a project, I get the following warning

```
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

I tried compiling after using `touch *` but i still get the same warning. Can somebody please tell me how i can rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error, per se, it's just `make` letting you know that some of the files have a timestamp newer than the current system time.  This happens when you copy files from the host onto the VM and the two clocks are out of sync (specifically, the VM system time is 'slower'/less than/earlier than the host's system time).

It's weird that `touch` doesn't make the warning disappear, though.  You can play around with the `-t` option to `touch` and see if a specific timestamp makes the warning go away:

```
   ` -t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time`
```